Application defined or object defined macro error
I have a macro code:
Sub Daily_ACH_Tables()
    ' Daily_ACH_Tables Macro
    Columns("A:H").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A:$H"), , xlYes).Name = "Table4"
    ' Moves to the next sheet
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    Columns("A:H").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A:$H"), , xlYes).Name = "Table5"
    Columns("A:H").Select
End Sub

The data in the rows will change day to day but the headers wont. How can I modify this macro so that no matter the amount of rows or data this macro will work? I did try to use chatgpt and it gave me this macro code as I dont know how to code at all but that code is not working at all and giving an error occurred application defined, or object defined error.
Sub Daily_ACH_Tables()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim tbl As ListObject
   Dim tblName As String
   Dim lastRow As Long
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
   ' Define the worksheet
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
   ' Find the last row with data in column A
   lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   ' Create table for the data in columns A to H
   Set tbl = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.Range("A1:H" & lastRow), , xlYes)
   ' Assign a name to the table
   tblName = "Table" & ws.ListObjects.Count
   ' Rename the table
   tbl.Name = tblName
   ' Clear any existing filters
   tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
   Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
   MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
End Sub


Is your code located in the workbook containing the sheets? What are the names of the sheets? Wouldn't you prefer more meaningful table names than Table4 and Table5?

Both your original code, and the ChatGPT code, work for me without error.

Here's one way to do it:
Sub Daily_ACH_Tables()
    Const NUM_SHEETS = 2 '# of sheets to process, beginning with activesheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet, f As Range, n As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'start with the active worksheet
    Do
        n = n + 1 'increment sheet count
        'find the last-used cell in A:H on `ws`
        Set f = ws.Range("A:H").Find(what:="*", searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                                     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then 'sheet has content?
            'create the table...
            ws.ListObjects.Add xlSrcRange, ws.Range("A1:H" & f.Row), , xlYes
        End If
        Set ws = ws.Next              'next worksheet (if any)
        If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Do 'no more sheets!
    Loop While n < NUM_SHEETS
End Sub

I didn't name the created tables - don't know if that's important for your use case?

Thank you! This works great, the only issue I am having now is that if my data changes for instance the amount in column A, it will only create a table on 1 sheet, not both. It only works as intended with my original data. If the data changes, (Headers are always the same) the macro doesnt work as intended. I can provide a sample workbook for better example.

Do you get any error message?  You can only run this once per sheet: when a table exists you can't create another one which covers the same range...  How exactly is your data changing?  Manually, or through some other process?

No error message. The process for this workbook will be to delete the existing tables daily and replace with new data and then run the macro. Its just that if the data changes in the columns, the macro only works on 1 sheet and not the other. I am trying to figure out now how to add a sample document so it's easier to understand.

You can upload a sample file to (eg) google drive, onedrive, etc etc.  Anywhere you can share a link to.  You can attach a file here on SO.

Here is a link to the sample file. Please lmk if this doesnt work. Thank you so much for your help thus far! https://file.io/9w4Lp8qvScnn

You'll need to outline the exact steps to take to reproduce the problem you're having when sheet content changes. If I run the code on your workbook as-is, it works as expected.

It works as expected in my sample workbook but when I try to run it on my actual workbook, its giving me an issue. The macro works for sheet 2 but not sheet 1. Here is the link for that workbook (I changed customer name for privacy purposes. https://file.io/ahtzylyNcCLE

If that link doesnt work for any reason, here is another link https://file.io/021EXubjvSL8. Thank you!

Sheet2 already has a table?  Sheet1 gets converted as expected but sheet2 will error (as expected)  Are you sure you're running the macro with the correct activesheet?

Prior to me running the macro, there are no tables on sheet 1 or sheet 2 as expected. When I run the macro, the macro is only working for 1 of the sheets vs creating a table on both sheets as intended.  This only happens if the data changes from the data that was used when I originally created the macro. The example workbook that I sent just shows what happened when I ran the macro.

If I convert the one table in that file back to a regular range and then run the macro, both sheets get processed as expected...

If the data were to change (Which it will from day to day) that is when I have issues with the macro where its not converting both tables, just 1 table. For instance, if I change the amounts or the amount of rows, the macro wont work as expected. I thought it would work regardless as long as the headers are the same but thats not the case.

It will work as long as you convert each listobject back to a regular range.  If you're having a problem I'd need to see the problem file before you run the macro on it, otherwise I can't reproduce the problem.

Thank you! If I have any additional errors, I will circle back and paste the  data prior to running the macro. Everything seems to be working as expected right now.
